# Location and width and height in one go

Tags: vb.net

I would like to move a control and set a new size in one go.

In VB6 I could say:

```
_Browser.Move(uLeft, uTop, uWidth, uHeight)
```

Now with VB.NET I only find this solution:

```
    _Browser.Location = New Point(uLeft, uTop)
    _Browser.Width = uWidth
    _Browser.Height = uHeight
```

I would like to ask if there is a method that allows me to set the location and the width and height in one statement.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in function for that, but it's pretty easy to write your own extension for it:

```
Public Module Extensions
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Sub Move(ByRef Ctrl As Control, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal Width As Integer, ByVal Height As Integer)
        Ctrl.Location = New Point(X, Y)
        Ctrl.Size = New Size(Width, Height)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Now you should be able to do:

```
_Browser.Move(uLeft, uTop, uWidth, uHeight)
```

**Read more about Extension Methods:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx

Comment: I have created a usercontrol, but it does not recognize my new "Move" extension. Do I have to do anything special to make it work with a usercontrol?

Comment: @user19127 : Copy the Sub along with the Extension tag, and change `Ctrl As Control` to `Ctrl As UserControl` (place it in the same Module).

Comment: I did that, but it wouldn't work anyways. I will investigate more when I have the time. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Strange thing it didn't work with UserControls... Will try it later.